# How to show values from 2 fields in a single textbox in an asp.net GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and a linqdatasource.  The GridView is editable and when the user clicks to edit a row I want to concatenate two of the fields in the linqdatasource and place it in a single textbox.

I tried something like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Field1") %> - <%# Bind("Field2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

That didn't work.

Comment: What output did this actually produced?

Comment: The code displays only Field2.  I'm not sure why.  It doesn't error, but does not show the Field1 or the "-".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't make sense to Bind two values in one textbox, though you can Eval two of them together like this

```
Text='<%# Eval("Field1","{0}") + "-" + Eval("Field2","{0}") %>'
```

The formatting parameter {0} isn't always needed.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Field1").ToString() + " " + Eval("Field2").ToString() %>'
```